# Call to a member function on a non object

Tags: php, class, object

**EasyCMS PHP**

```
 <?php
   $sql="";
   $query="";
   $content="";
   $row="";
   $d="";
   class easyCMS { 
     public $connect;
     public function content($content){
       $sql="SELECT $content FROM easyCMS";
   $query = mysqli_query($this->connect,$sql);
   $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
   return $row[0];
     }
     public function update($d,$k){
       $sql = "UPDATE easyCMS SET $d=$k";
   $query = mysqli_query($this->connect,$sql);
     }
   }
 ?>
```

Then later I add this in my `index.php`

**index php**

```
 <?php
  include_once('database.php');
  include_once('easyCMS.php');
  $easyCMS->connect = $connect; 
  $easyCMS = new easyCMS($connect);
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
     <?php echo $easyCMS->content('index'); ?>
   </body>
  </html>
```

But I get this error each time

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function content() on a non-object in .../index.php on line 16
```

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `$connect` is not defined

Comment: Well the error message in the title is going to be his next problem ..

Comment: `$easyCMS` does not appear to be difined. Need `$easyCMS = new easyCMS` and which is line 19?

Comment: Although there are undefined variables, the error is a syntax error. Undefined variables don't raise a syntax error.

Comment: Oops I added wrong error :X

Comment: ok so I see what @mseifert said let me fix that :/

Comment: @MarkBaker No, method calls on uninstantiated objects raise a fatal error, not a syntax error.

Comment: @aldanux `$connect` is defined it's in the `db.php`

Comment: @EasyBB Uuh no, if `$connect` is defined in `db.php` then it's not in the scope of `function content()`

Comment: Oh, ok yeah I just found that out in my new errors. Why is that? And how would I ensure it is in the scope? Do I add the `include` inside `easyCMS`

Comment: @EasyBB read up about [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: Ok I will. Thanks dbf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will now post as an answer now that you have corrected the error message. This seems more clearly to be the likely source of the error.

$easyCMS does not appear to be defined. You need to create the object before referencing it methods and properties:

```
$easyCMS = new easyCMS;
```

You should add the connect var to the class and reference it with `$this->connect` within the scope of the class. Set the value of `$this->connect` by passing $connect to it when creating a new instance of the class: `$easyCMS = new easyCMS($connect);` The full code is as follows:

```
class easyCMS {  
    public $connect;

    public function __construct($connect){
        $this->connect = $connect;
    }


  public function content($content){
     $sql="SELECT $content FROM easyCMS";
 $query = mysqli_query($this->connect,$sql);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
 return $row[0];
 }
 public function update($d,$k){
   $sql = "UPDATE easyCMS SET $d=$k";
   $query = mysqli_query($this->connect,$sql);
 }
```

index.php

```
<?php
  include_once('database.php');
  include_once('easyCMS.php');
  $easyCMS = new easyCMS($connect);
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
     <?php echo $easyCMS->content('index'); ?>
   </body>
  </html>
?>
```

Comment: How do I ensure `$connect` is in the scope of the functions `content()` and `update()` ?

Comment: The easiest way is to have a class variable which you can set. I will update the answer to show.

Comment: I've added an update to my OP I'm still getting the same parameter 1 needs to be mysqli error for some reason.

Comment: oh ok... GRRR `mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given `

Comment: OK - I've updated the code to show the flow. Passing `$connect` requires adding the `__construct` method as shown. Then remove the line above it: `$easyCMS->connect = $connect;`. Note: `$easyCMS` should not be referenced until after the `new easyCMS` statement.

Comment: `Missing argument 1 for easyCMS::__construct()` I'm sorry this class object is new to me, I'm trying to learn before college starts back up. I am a self taught person and am best when I write the code and reading the docs is hard for me honestly.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the `$connect` argument in `$easyCMS = new easyCMS($connect);`? The code above should work.